# Jquery Ajax Post is not calling action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

```
function CreateModalDialogWindow(urlPath) {
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Popup","Project")',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        $('#dialog').html(data).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });
    },
    error: function(){
       alert('Error!');
    }
});

return false;
```

}

I wanted to call an actionmethod using ajax post. Here is the action method

```
 [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Popup()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Project/Popup.cshtml");
    }
```

Please let me know what is wrong in the above code.

Comment: Why is there debugger; in the success function? Possible you also wan't to disable cache: cache : false

Answer (score 3):

There might be different reasons why the action method is not being called:

- you have some javascript error
- you never call the `CreateModalDialogWindow` function
- you call the `CreateModalDialogWindow` in the click of a link or form submit but you forgot to cancel the default action of this button by returning false.

So start by first calling this code in the document ready to see if it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Popup", "Project")',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#dialog').html(data).dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                width: 400,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now if you put a breakpoint in your controller action it should normally be hit. I would recommend you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug which will help you see any possible javascript errors and see the exact requests/responses being sent during AJAX requests.

You will also notice that I have removed the `async: false` switch because this makes synchronous calls to the server freezing the web browser during the execution of this request and thus you are no longer doing AJAX.

Comment: Dimitrov, Action method is not getting called even if i place this code inside a document.ready(). But the same code worked fine in a sample app.

Comment: Dimitrov, After debugging in firebug i could notice that it is throwing an error like "405 method not allowed". Am i missing anything in the url section.

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts: Thanks Huybrechts. But still it is not working. In firebug i could see that it's throwing an error "405 method not allowed"

Comment: Thanks guys, url in the ajax post wrong. i have corrected it, it's working fine now. Thanks :)